# perl qw() function assigning lines instead of words

Tags: arrays, perl, line

In Perl

```
@array=qw/this is a line
          and a new one
          then a new one
          ......     
             ........./;
```

will result in each 'word' being assigned to the @array variables.
How can i make each 'line' to be assigned to @array variables i.e $a[0]="this is a line" instead of $a[0]="this"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
my @array = split / *\n */,
            qq/this is a line
               and a new one
               and another/;
```

Comment: Your editor might have tabs and regexp /[ \t]*\n[ \t]*/ might be more resilient. 
Another one /\s*\n\s*/ might work too but note that it would eliminate empty lines if you have them.